# Upgrade tailwind css version in existing react/tailwind css app

Tags: reactjs, version, tailwind-css

I made react app with `Tailwind CSS` version 2, now they have new version 3.0.

The version i have in my app needs `craco` to run, and i saw in the new documentation of installing `Tailwind CSS` with `react` app that the `craco` step doesn't exist anymore.

So how can I upgrade to version 3?

Thank you in advance!!

Comment: Did the answers solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this:

1. `npm uninstall craco`
2. [Follow](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/upgrade-guide) the **upgrade process** `Tailwind CSS project from v2 to V3` precisely.
3. Apply the `required` changes